# Non-selfadjoint operators and physical systems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, brownian-motion, heat-equation, navier-stokes

There are plenty of examples of non-selfadjoint operators modelizing physical phenomena: to name a few, let's quote the the heat equation (\ref{HEAT}, see below), the Navier-Stokes system for incompressible fluids (\ref{NSI}, see below), the Kolmogorov equation, describing Brownian motion (\ref{KOL}, see below). We have with $D=-i\nabla$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\vert{D}\vert^2 u=0, \qquad \vert{D}\vert^2=-\sum_{1\le j\le n}\partial_{x_j}^2,\tag{HEAT}
\label{HEAT}
\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\mathbb P\bigl((\text{curl }u)\times u\bigr)+\nu\ \text{curl}^2 u=0, \qquad \mathbb P=I_n-\frac{D\otimes D}{\vert{D}\vert^2}\text{is the Leray projector,}\tag{NSI}
\label{NSI}
\\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+v\partial_x f+\vert{D_v}\vert^2 f=0, \qquad 
\text{$f$ is a non-negative function of $(t, x,v)$}.\tag{KOL}
\label{KOL}  
\end{align}
Note that $u(t,x)$ in \eqref{NSI} is a 3D vector field.
However in these three examples the structure is somewhat similar with
$$
\text{Transport term}+\text{non-negative diffusion term},
$$
with significant complications when a non-linearity occurs in the transport term, which is moreover non-local in \eqref{NSI}.

**My question, at last.** Is there a recorded physical phenomenon described by an evolution equation of type
$$
\text{Transport term}+\text{self-adjoint term}
$$
without assuming that the self-adjoint term is non-negative? Several examples of this type were studied by Nirenberg & Treves and Mizohata in the sixties with a complete characterization of their solvability properties; this is the case for instance of the 2D operator
$$
\mathcal L_2=\partial_t+ t^2D_x.
$$
Of course, one should not study there the Cauchy problem starting at time 0, but set the Cauchy datum at  time $t=-1$ when $\xi >0$ and at  time $t=1$ when $\xi <0$
(that could be at time $t=-\infty$ when $\xi >0$ and at  time $t=+\infty$ when $\xi <0$).
Anyhow, there are several mathematically well-understood equations  of type $\mathcal L_2$, although it is not clear that it is indeed related to an actual physical system.

Comment: Such problems arise in the study of phase transitions.

Comment: Reminds me of negative viscosty in certain flows, e.g. see : Słomka, Jonasz, and Jörn Dunkel. "Geometry-dependent viscosity reduction in sheared active fluids." Physical Review Fluids 2.4 (2017): 043102.

Comment: Thanks for the two comments. About phase transitions, would you have a reference?